# Accessing string resources inside network-security-config

Tags: android, pinning

Is it possible to use [string resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource) inside `android:networkSecurityConfig` defined in AndroidManifest.xml?

I have a config file like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
  <domain-config>
    <domain includeSubdomains="true">mydomain.com</domain>
    <pin-set>
      <pin digest="SHA-256">@string/pin</pin>
      <pin digest="SHA-256">@string/pin_fallback</pin>
    </pin-set>
    <trustkit-config enforcePinning="true" disableDefaultReportUri="true">
    </trustkit-config>
  </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

but my app doesn't seem to detect resources I define in `res/values/strings.xml`. Hardcoding these strings works just fine though.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using **Gradle Plugin 7.0.0** or later then you can use string interpolation using `${}` like this. the **${dynamicVariable}** syntax includes the dynamic variable in the PIN value using string interpolation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
  <domain-config>
    <domain includeSubdomains="true">mydomain.com</domain>
    <pin-set>
      <pin digest="SHA-256">@{getString(R.string.pin)}${dynamicVariable}</pin>
      <pin digest="SHA-256">@{getString(R.string.pin_fallback)}${dynamicVariable}</pin>
    </pin-set>
    <trustkit-config enforcePinning="true" disableDefaultReportUri="true">
    </trustkit-config>
  </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

**Note:** if you are using **Gradle Plugin** having less then **7.0.0** then it is not possible to use dynamic accessing string resources